# Theorem 4.3 from Beckenbach and Bellman.

Tags: calculus, inequality

The theorem states that

> $\displaystyle \frac{{a}_{1} + {a}_{2} + \cdot \cdot \cdot  + a_n} {n} \ge \sqrt[n]{{a_1}{a_2}\cdot \cdot \cdot{a_n}}\tag{1}$

Very briefly, having previously proven

> $ \displaystyle \frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}\tag{2}$

and now letting

> $\displaystyle a = \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$ and  $\displaystyle b = \frac{a_3+a_4}{2}$

we get

> $\displaystyle \frac{a_1 +a_2 +a_3 +a_4}{4} \ge \sqrt{\left(\frac{a_1 + a_2}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a_3 + a_4}{2}\right)}\tag{3}$

Using the fact that the AM $\ge$ GM  (i.e., using $(2)$), then simplifying, we get

> $${ \displaystyle \frac{a_1 +a_2 +a_3 +a_4}{4} \ge \sqrt{\sqrt{a_1a_2}\sqrt{a_3a_4}} \ge (a_1a_2a_3a_4)^\frac{1}{4} }\tag{4}$$

Question:

Referring to $(4)$, the first inequality is a restatement of the fact that the 'arithmetic mean' is $\ge$ the 'geometric mean', and expected. But, the second inequality seems to me to be an 'equality', as the last entity is a (??simplified) restatement of the second entity. Could someone explain why the second inequality is presented as it is?

Comment: There are many InEqualities in your Post. It would help to number these and then refer with first or second !

Comment: @Prem Good point. I edited the question.

Comment: you are correct. The second inequality in the last expression should be an equality.

Comment: I have answered with similar thoughts , where I have used InEquality in first line, **Explicit Equality in middle line**, and InEquality in last line. The Text book is using a "ShortCut" , @sku !!

Comment: Yes, it is an equality. I think it is kind of typo, though $A \ge A$ is ok. This was in the book (1975). If you looked at the book "Inequalities"(1961) by the same authors, Ch. 1, Page 4, it is an equality. See: https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Inequalities%20-%20Beckenbach%20E.,%20Bellman%20R.%201961.pdf

Comment: Thank you all who commented. It reinforces in me, which I really like about this wonderful discipline, ambiguity is simply not tolerated.

Comment: Do you not agree with my answer , @user1115542 , where I have explained why the writer used InEquality instead of Equality ? I have used Equality in the alternative but longer way !

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thanks for making my question much more understandable.

Comment: @Prem (I did not downvote your answer.) I think it is just $\frac{a_1 +a_2 +a_3 +a_4}{4} \ge \sqrt{\sqrt{a_1a_2}\sqrt{a_3a_4}} = (a_1a_2a_3a_4)^\frac{1}{4}$, rather than 'ShortCut'.

Comment: When writers want to state "$X1 = X2 = X3 \ge X4=X5=X6$" where **cumbersome terms** are involved , some readers might skim over the large long terms and check only the first and last relations and wrongly take "X1 = X6" ; Some writers choose to **knowingly** write that like this "$X1 = X2 = X3 \ge X4 \ge X5 \ge X6$" , where the last 3 relations are made InEqualities , but we can get at a glance that "$X1 \ge X6$" ; These "ShortCuts" are well known as **Abuse of Notation** , not typo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation , @RiverLi , Having said that, I will be Deleting my Answer !!!